# Why HBase use tombstone marker? Why not delete it directly

Tags: hbase

As per the hbase it never delete any record, instead of this it add a tombstone marker to it. My question is why tombstone? Can we get our records back which are marked as tombstone before major compaction? And if not what is the purpose to keep the deleted record  by marking them as tombstone?

Comment: What would be gained by "deleting the record directly" (and what does that even mean exactly)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please ask specific programming question.

Comment: What is the purpose of keeping the record in data base once it is deleted by marking it as tombstone?

Comment: any chance to approve answer?

Answer (score 2):

Hbase data files HFiles are immutable and can not delete one deleted record from it when you send delete command, so it adds another record for deleted keys, and when major compact happens, it deletes records and combines small Hfiles if necessary. This is a design decision.

Comment: thanks Halil, that's really clear my doubt about hbase delete operation.